# Input data (a part of a kolom) from a different file with the same date in the kolom

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to import data from a column in an different file with the same date in the column.
On one sheet i have 7 dates created in different columns with

```
    15-09-15    16-09-15    17-09-15    18-09-15    19-09-15    20-09-15    21-09-15
```

O
M
N

Now will i show data from cells from a column from a different file with the same date as a cell in the kolom where will be paste the data.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution with a formule and not with a macro.
With using the formule HLOOKUP() i have the right result.